# Angular ui.bootstrap.alert have no styling

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying out Angular ui bootstrap but I'm having trouble getting it to work. I want to use the alert directive.

What I have done is added the following to my html header:

```
<link href="stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="javascripts/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.13.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="javascripts/angularApp.js"></script>
```

This is my html for the alerts:

```
<alert ng-repeat="alert in alerts" type="{{alert.type}}" close="closeAlert($index)">{{alert.msg}}</alert>
```

I inject the dependency to ui.bootstrap:

```
var app = angular.module('e-log', ['ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap']);
```

My controller looks like this:

```
$scope.alerts = [];
var addAlert = function (type, msg) {
    $scope.alerts.push({
        "type": type,
        "msg": msg
    });
};
addAlert("success", "A message");

$scope.closeAlert = function(index) {
    $scope.alerts.splice(index, 1);
}
```

Now when I load the page, the html looks like this:

```
<alert ng-repeat="alert in alerts" type="success" close="closeAlert($index)" class="ng-binding ng-scope">A message</alert>
```

It shows as plain text, there's no way to close it down and it has no styling at all.

What I've tried to do is add this to a plunker and that works just fine. Am I injecting the dependency correctly? Could it be that I also use regular bootstrap in my code? Any tips on what could be causing this would be greatly appriceated =)!

EDIT: edited according to the advice I've gotten so far.

Comment: You're including `ui.bootstrap` after your app..

Comment: True! That didn't seem to fix it though...

Comment: A couple of things.  You don't use both Angular UI Bootstrap JS and Bootstrap's JS file.  But most importantly, 0.13.4 requires Angular 1.3+ and you're using 1.2.19.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

1. You don't use both Angular UI Bootstrap **AND** Bootstrap Javascript files together.  It's not necessary.  You almost certainly only want the Angular UI Bootstrap one.
2. Most importantly, you're using Angular 1.2.19 and Angular UI Bootstrap **REQUIRES** Angular 1.3+.  [See here](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) for the minimal dependencies.

Comment: Thanks alot, this was the problem. I should probably start reading the documentation more carefully from now on!

Answer (score 0):

I think there are 3 problems with your setting up above

1. With `addAlert` method first parameter, alert **type** should be `success` not `Success`.
2. Also with `addAlert` method, it takes **3** parameters but you only give it **2** parameters when you call it - ie. (*Success*, *A message*). The most important params are **type** and **msg** but you give **msg** to be **undefined**.
3. You can not close the alert because you do not give your controller scope method to handle it. Add :

   ```
   $scope.closeAlert = function(index) {
       $scope.alerts.splice(index, 1);
   }
   ```

   should fix this problem.

[Link fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9832v8k2/) for your preference

Comment: Thanks for your comment! You are correct on all your points, but that was mistakes from me creating this post. I am 99% sure my code in the controller/html works, since that fiddle of yours work with the same code that I have.

Is there any way that I can see if the ui.bootstrap is injected correctly?

Comment: Hmm I think you can try bootstrap `tooltip` to check if `ui.bootstrap` works in your app or not. But I doubt the problem does not relate to the injection of `ui.bootstrap` in your app.

Comment: You're right, tooltip works properly so it shouldn't be an issue with the injection as you say. But I can't see what can cause this... 
To be sure I copy-pasted your fiddle code in to my html/controller and still no styling on the message. Just plain text. :(